# Error after addition of bash_completion into root's .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, root

I added the following lines into my `/root/.bashrc` file to enable to bash completion:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
   /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

But I receive the following error saying that I don't have rights to execute it...

```
bash: /etc/bash_completion: Permission non accordée
```

I also tried replacing the command's launch by the following command `su -c /etc/bash_completion` but nothing changed at all...
Can someone show me a way to avoid this error ?

Comment: This might help: `help source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `/etc/bash_completion` didn't had execution rights.
I executed the following command and it now works : `su -c chmod a+x /etc/bash_completion`